# swift get topmostViewController avoid UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, topmost

i want to get topMostVC so i did this function:

```
    func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController {
        
        if let presented = self.presentedViewController {
            return presented.topMostViewController()
        }
        
        if let navigation = self as? UINavigationController {
            return navigation.visibleViewController?.topMostViewController() ?? navigation
        }
        
        if let tab = self as? UITabBarController {
            return tab.selectedViewController?.topMostViewController() ?? tab
        }
        
        return self
    }
```

Then called using:

```
AppDelegate.shared.window?.rootViewController?.topMostViewController()
```

But i have problem is when UIAlertController is showing in screen, it's return UIAlertController, not my expect viewcontroller

Can anyone tech me how to avoid UIAlertController, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more condition

```
if let presented = self.presentedViewController,
   !(presented is UIAlertController) { // <== Here or use !presented.isKind(of: UIAlertController.self)
    return presented.topMostViewController()
}
```

Comment: if presented is UIAlertController then it will return nothing.

Comment: What do you mean presented is UIAlertController ?

Comment: UIAlertController presenting on screen, in that case what it will return?

Comment: It returns the base controller and that's the question "How to get the controller without alert controller"

Comment: oh sorry i missed to read your code. Thanks